# Windows 10 startmenu not working

Tags: windows-10

The start menu is not working on computers with Windows 10 (version 1709) when using the roaming profiles (v6). It's not possible to open it or to confirm the start button. The search bar and the status bar aren't working, too.

Here is what I tried to fix this issue:

- fix with sfc and dism (option "restorehealth")
- delete the user directory and rejoin after restart
- change user profile from roaming to local
- run startmenu.diagcab from Microsoft
- Powershell:

`Get-appxpackage -all *shellexperience* -packagetype bundle |% {add-appxpackage -register -disabledevelopmentmode ($_.installlocation + “\appxmetadata\appxbundlemanifest.xml”)}`

How can I fix this issue without reinstalling or resetting the computer?

Comment: do you see ShellExperienceHost.exe crashes in Eventlog?

Comment: Unfortunately no relevant ones.

Comment: does start work with local profiles? or does it only fail with roaming profiles?

Comment: It doesn't work with local profiles, too. Only with the local profile of the predefined administrator apparently. I deleted the user profiles and rejoined again. The problem still occurs.

Comment: update one of the PCs where it fails to 1803 and look if this fixes it.

Comment: I solved the problem. It was Kaspersky which prevented the start menu to be opened.

Comment: post this as answer and how you analyzed this.

Comment: I removed Kaspersky from the system and after reboot the start menu finally worked again. From that experience we have decided to change the anti virus solution. The Kaspersky version was the latest version and nevertheless it caused such issues.